# «Принеси поесть»

Tags: синтаксис, выбор-слов

Возможно ли такое словосочетание? ***Поесть*** — дополнение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Поесть** — дополнение?

Да, **дополнение**. Принесёт ОН, а есть будете ВЫ.